# Maven dependency issue in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have multiple related projects open in a workspace in eclipse. One of the projects has a maven dependency on the output jar from another project. In this project, any references to the classes in the dependency always show up as red (unidentified) and I get no code completion or javadoc showing up for them. If I manually add the jar to the classpath, then I no longer have this problem. The thing is, I don't want to have to manually add the jar every time our revision changes, that's what Maven is for. Any ideas on how I can resolve this? it seems like a bug to me, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Configured the workspace resolution Eclipse ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is the following:

- Make sure that `m2e` or `m2eclipse` (depending on your version of Eclipse) is installed: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/
- Use the dependencies section in the POM file exclusively, don't fiddle with the Eclipse project references. Right-click the project, then select *Maven > Update Project Configuration* to reset the project to the Maven default settings. This way, *m2e* has ownership of the dependencies.
- If you don't have that option, you might need to enable the project for Maven usage. Right-click the project, then *Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution* or *Maven > Enable Dependency Management*.
- Make sure all referenced projects are open in Eclipse and have the Maven *nature* enabled.
- Check the Maven settings for each project, make sure that *groupId*, *artifactId* and *version* match with the projects you have open in Eclipse. So if the project you depend on has version *1.0.0-SNAPSHOT* in Eclipse, make sure that the depending project's POM file references version *1.0.0-SNAPSHOT* in the *dependencies* section.
- Enable *Workspace Resolution* for each of the projects. Right-click the project, then *Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution*.
- Finally, if the projects are still not resolved, right-click the project again, then *Maven > Update Dependencies*

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved the problem by right-clicking on the project and selecting Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution from the context menu. I had already tried updating the project from the POM file as described above.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this typically you can copy the Eclipse .classpath file from a working project since there isn’t anything project specific here assuming you’re structured as a standard Maven project. This will tell Eclipse to allow Maven to manage the dependencies and build. There seems to be no easy way to do this from the Eclipse UI.